# jQuery Validate required not working, I want know why

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, http-status-code-400

I am trying to validate my form submission using jqueryvalidation.js .
 the Browser response like that

```
     HTTP Status 400 -

     type Status report

     message

     description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

I use this code but validation not working

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src = "${contextPath }/static/js/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='${contextPath}/static/ace_admin1.3.1/assets/js/jquery.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src = "${contextPath }/static/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $.validator.setDefaults({
                submitHandler: function() {
                  alert("sumbit");
                }
            });
                $(function() {
                    $("#subjectForm").validate({
                            rules: {
                                name : {
                                    required: true,
                                    },
                                testCount : {
                                    required: true,
                                    },
                                totalTime : {
                                    required: true,
                                    },
                                totalScore : {
                                    required: true,
                                    }
                                },
                            });
                        });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>

                                <form id="subjectForm " action="${contextPath }/teacher/testAddSubject" method="POST">
                                <p>add</p>
                                <p><label>subjectName</label><input name = "name" type ="text"/></p>
                                <p><label>Description</label><input name = "description" type ="text"/></p>
                                <p><label>number</label><input name = "testCount" type ="text"/></p>
                                <p><label>time</label><input name = "totalTime" type ="text"/></p>
                                <p><label>grade</label><input name = "totalScore" type ="text" /></p>
                                <button type="submit">submit</button>
                                </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I don't know where is error, please help me.it about jQuery version and jQuery Validate version?

Comment: First off: `${contextPath }` is not your actual code... the code that's ***rendered*** in the browser is what the JavaScript is using.  Secondly, your problem has nothing to do with JavaScript.  Here is the definition of status code 400:  *"The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the extra space at the end of...

```
id="subjectForm "
```

It's breaking your JavaScript.  With broken JavaScript, jQuery Validate will not initialize.

**Working DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/1crgtu7y/](http://jsfiddle.net/1crgtu7y/)**

*(You'd also need to include jQuery Migrate **AFTER** jQuery)*

---

As far as your status code 400:

> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

This has absolutely nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.

This is [something else entirely](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> **400 Bad Request**: The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

So I suggest that you inspect the ***rendered*** DOM in your browser and make sure every server request (URL) is formed properly.  Also, look at your server-side script at `${contextPath}/teacher/testAddSubject` and make sure it's not broken.